# Jenkins pipeline job to perform a docker login to remote repository fails due to Login: command not found error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a **jenkins pipeline job** that I use to perform a **docker login** to a remote repository in AWS.

My pipeline script looks like this:

```
node {
    
    stage 'Login to remote ECR'
    sh "\$(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 0000000000.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com)"

}
```

This fails due to:

```
++ docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 0000000000.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
++ aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-1

+ Login Succeeded
/home/myUser/.jenkins/workspace/myProject1@tmp/durable-7577883f/script.sh: line 1: Login: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Does anyone know why it fails?? It does say Login Suceeded but still fails. I am puzzled.

Comment: Is this the only command which you are executing in the node?

Comment: Yes, only command!

Comment: Do you want to login to aws registry as well as docker hub?

Comment: Same error as before unfortunately. Is my pipeline wrong syntax wise?

Comment: Syntax wise, can you make one change? do `stage("Login to remote ECR") {sh "command1" sh "command2"}`. Try this. And separate both the commands. Also first try only with aws ecr command and see whether you are able to logged in or not.

Comment: I think you don't need to use the `\$(...)`. You directly can use the 
    
    `sh "aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 0000000000.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"`